# Create an instance of a class within another class with values passed in through user input

Tags: java, string, class, pointers, return

I have two classes: `Animal` and `Shelter`.
I have a `toString` method that is supposed to print out the name of the Shelter plus all of the information from the animal, all gathered through user input through the scanner class. However, when I create an instance of the Animal within the Shelter class, there obviously aren't any values in that instance yet.

**Question: How do I point the values gathered in through user input to the shelter class so it can print out the `shelterName` with the `toString()`method?**

**User input:**

```
public class AnimalShelter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is your animal's name?");
        String animalName = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your animal's type?");
        String type = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your animal's age?");
        int age = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the name of your animal shelter?");
        String shelterName = scan.nextLine();
        Shelter myShelter = new Shelter(shelterName);
        System.out.println(shelterName.toString());

    }

}
```

**Animal class:**

```
public class Animal {

private String animalName;
private String type;
private int age;

    public Animal(String animalName, String type, int age)
    {
        this.animalName = animalName;
        this.type = type;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getAnimalName()
    {
        return animalName;
    }

    public String getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
```

}

**Shelter class: *How do I point the values from user input into the `myAnimal` object*?**

```
public class Shelter {

    Animal myAnimal = new Animal(); 

    private String shelterName;

    public Shelter(String shelterName)
    {
        this.shelterName = shelterName;
    }

    public String toString(Animal myAnimal)
    {
        myAnimal.getAnimalName();
        myAnimal.getType();
        myAnimal.getAge();
        return "" + shelterName + myAnimal.getAnimalName() + myAnimal.getType() + myAnimal.getAge();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample code you have an animal class which you never used. I am against spoon fed answers but im in a good mood so ill explain this to you line by line.

```
public class AnimalShelter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Save user input as temp variable values
        System.out.println("What is your animal's name?");
        String animalName = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your animal's type?");
        String type = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your animal's age?");
        int age = scan.nextInt();
         //Create an instance of your Animal class passing your temp variables
        Animal animal= new Animal(animalName,type,age);
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the name of your animal shelter?");
        String shelterName = scan.nextLine();

        //Create your Shelter class here passing the shelter name
        Shelter myShelter = new Shelter(shelterName);

        //Use the same class to pass your animal class(the one where you placed the attributes in) into the Shelter class.
        System.out.println(myShelter.toString(animal));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Append the following code to the tail of your main() method:

```
Animal animal = new Animal(animalName, type, age);
System.out.println(myShelter.toString(animal));
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you probably don't want to!

Here, your `Animal` and `Shelter` classes seem mostly well set up, but they don't actually need to be linked like this.

Consider instead, creating `Animal`s in your `main(...)` method, and then using a new method to 'add' them to an existing shelter.

For example:

```
public class Shelter {
    // Animal myAnimal = new Animal(); Remove this
    private  String shelterName; // This is good.
    public Shelter(..) // This is fine too

    public String toString(...) // This works, perhaps?
    // New method here, with list
    private ArrayList<Animal> listOfAnimals_
    public void addAnimal(Animal newAnimal)
    {
        listOfAnimals_.add(newAnimal);
    }
}
```

Then from `main`:

```
Animal TimTheCow = new Animal ("Tim", "Cow", 5);
myShelter.addAnimal(TimTheCow);
```

This removes some of the strong coupling that you don't need, and reduces pressure to pass arguments around.

If you wanted to list all the `Animal`s of the `Shelter`, you'd change your `toString` method to something like:

```
public String toString()
{
    String newStr;
    for ( Animal animal : listOfAnimals ) // apologies if bad syntax
    {
        newStr += animal.toString();
    }
    return "" + shelterName + newStr;
}
```

and in your `Animal` class,

```
public String toString()
{
    return "" + getAnimalName() + getType() + getAge();
}
```